# Does anyone know what plant this is?

Tags: identification, shrubs, weeds

[image: Picture2]I have this plant growing in my garden. I am wondering what plant it is 
It's not tall. probably like 1-2 inches. The roots are not deep. But it's almost like a creeper.

[image: I have this plant growing in my garden. I am wondering what plant it is]

Comment: Optimcode, welcome! We can probably answer better with a bit more information: Where in the world is your garden (a rough idea is fine, not your street address), how large is the plant and in what kind of location (sun, shade, dry, wet..) does it thrive? Can you tell us a bit about how it changes during the seasons - or maybe stays the same? You can always [edit] your post with details. And I always recommend the [tour] and browsing through [help].

Comment: I think the genus is Portulaca, based on the round and neat aspect of the stems, but I don't know the species.

Comment: Is this as tall as it gets, like, just an inch or so above ground level? Ever seen any flowers?

Comment: It's not tall. probably like 1-2 inches. No flowers.The roots are not deep. But it's almost like a creeper. It's around the wet soil. I live in Virginia.